# Azure Role Environment not initialising

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, seh, azure-role-environment

My project has suddenly stopped working. I am using local storage and when I try to initialise the role environment, it says:

> "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Error: 102 : Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE"

and an SEH exception occurs with error code "-2147467259". I start a new instance of the cloud part of my project and then attempt to start a new instance of my WPF application in the same solution. I think when the WPF application is run, it stops the cloud instance deployment. But I am not sure.

Comment: Stop adding "URGENT" to your title, Steven. Everything's urgent. It just moves people to ignore your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's an SEHException, this could be related to another answer I gave, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957938/why-am-i-getting-sehexception-when-calling-roleenvironment-getconfigurationsetti/2962705#2962705).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. When i check if the role enviroment is availale, it says false. Any idea why this is happening? I ran another azure project of mine and the role enviroment is available for that one

Comment: Make sure your Azure project is the startup project.