# MVC System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException When run on LocalHost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, localhost

I have a MVC WEBSITE that is published on Azure. If i run on debug mode on Visual studio, everything goes ok, however when i publish the website on my local iis so i can debug and alter quickly i get a "System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception"
The stack trace i receive is

[SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.]
   RdGetApplicationConfigurationSetting(UInt16* , UInt16** ) +0
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Internal.InteropRoleManager.GetConfigurationSetting(String name, String& ret) +184
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(String configurationSettingName) +92
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureCommon.TopologyHelper.TryGetServiceConfigurationSetting(String value, String& result) +56
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureCommon.DiagnosticsUtility.GetDiagnosticLevel(String propertyName) +63
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureCommon.DiagnosticsUtility.GetClientLogLevel() +30

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +537
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +35
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactoryConfiguration.Initialize(String clientName) +233
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheFactoryWrapper.CreateDataCacheFactoryConfiguration(String dataCacheClientName) +92
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider.CreateInternalProvider(IHttpRuntime httpRuntime, SessionInitializationData initData, IDataCacheFactory dataCacheFactory, EventHandler`1 cacheFetching, EventHandler`1 cacheFetched) +74
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider.GetInternalProvider() +206
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider.CreateNewStoreData(HttpContext context, Int32 timeout) +19
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.InitStateStoreItem(Boolean addToContext) +158
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.CompleteAcquireState() +356
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +1093
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +570
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +1536

Any Idea how to fix this please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting SEHException when calling RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("MYKEY")?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957938/why-am-i-getting-sehexception-when-calling-roleenvironment-getconfigurationsetti)

Comment: Hi, I tried it, it did not work, the problem was the Azure Caching. Has soon has i disabled chaching it started to work (had to run project on debug to start the azure emulator servive either way, but it works now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the Azure Caching. Has soon has i disabled chaching it started to work (had to run project on debug to start the azure emulator servive either way, but it works now)