# asp.net/azure debugger throwing SEHException error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, azure

So, I'm getting following error while running a web app on visual studio 2010 with azure SDK 1.8. I tried to find solution online and tried to do everything suggested but couldn't fix this problem. I do not have any trusteer app or rappor!t on my machine. Please help.

I have set up my cloud project as my start up project. Whole web application has 12 projects in it, including 3 different cloud project and I made sure I set everything up correctly. It was working fine before but a couple of days ago, I started getting this error.

[image]

Comment: Did you look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2962705/272109) I posted a long time ago? From the looks of your URL, I don't think you're running as an Azure service.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at it and made sure that I have set up my cloud project as my startup project. Whole web application has 12 projects in it, including 3 cloud project and I made sure I set up correctly. It was working fine before but a couple of days ago, I started getting this error.