# unhandled exception in Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I am in way over my head here, trying to program a code to work on a website in Azure. This is just supposed to be a demonstration for a presentation I have in the cloud. I wont be getting marks on this program, but it helps me to display the capabilities offered by Azure.

This may be vague, but if you can take a look at this error message and let me know if there's anything obvious let me know.

```
[SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.]
RdGetApplicationConfigurationSetting(UInt16* , UInt16** ) +0
RoleEnvironmentGetConfigurationSettingValueW(UInt16* pszName, UInt16* pszDest, UInt32 cchDest, UInt32* pcchRequiredDestSize) +47
 Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Internal.InteropRoleManager.GetConfigurationSetting(String name, String& ret) +91
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(String configurationSettingName) +67
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(String configurationSettingName) +67
ContosoAdsWeb.MvcApplication.InitializeStorage() in C:\a\src\ContosoAdsWeb\Global.asax.cs:32
ContosoAdsWeb.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\a\src\ContosoAdsWeb\Global.asax.cs:26

[HttpException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.]
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +4467101
System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +364
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +290

[HttpException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +4531288
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +94
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +191
```

Comment: You should post some code and add some detail about what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Azure Web Apps (websites). That being the case: Looks like you're making calls to `RoleEnvironment`, which is specifically for web/worker roles, and not Web Apps.

I posted a similar answer several years ago, with a bit more detail, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2962705/272109).